# Highcharts reset y Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, reset

First, I have several charts on my page - To make it more easy to compare data within the different charts, I'm setting the maximum yAxis to the highest one that is available.

**Question**: How do I revert the maximum I've just set without refetching the data? I'm looking for something like "autoscale" as it works if I add a maximum value of 11245, the maximum yAxis is something like 12500. I would like to restore all my charts.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wiesson/0p4z1mfj

```
$('#setMax').click(function (ev) {
    var yAxisMax = 0;
    $('[data-chart]').each(function (item) {
        var c = $(this).highcharts();
        if (c.yAxis[0].max > yAxisMax) {
            yAxisMax = c.yAxis[0].max;
        }
    });

    $('[data-chart]').each(function (item) {
        c = $(this).highcharts();
        if (c.yAxis[0].max < yAxisMax) {
            c.yAxis[0].update({
                max: yAxisMax
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply remove extremes from axis. In general, I would suggest using `axis.setExtremes(min, max)` instead of `axis.update(options)`. `setExtremes` should have much better performance in compare to `update`.

Code:

```
$('#setDefault').click(function (ev) {
    $('[data-chart]').each(function (item) {
        $(this).highcharts().yAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);
    });
});
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0p4z1mfj/9/

Comment: This solution was exceptionally helpful for a chart where I pushed out the axis extremes to avoid cutoff of chart elements, but needed to redraw it with new data. Setting the extremes back to default using "null" prevented the chart from continuously expanding after each redraw.

Comment: Which elements were cut off? It rather should not happen.

Comment: I had a bubble chart where certain bubbles would get cut off on one edge. I used `setExtremes()` to push out the axes by one unit to allow them to fit. Your answer above for null to reset the extremes is what I used when redrawing the chart: reset extremes, redraw chart, push out extremes by one unit, repeat.

Comment: Oh, bubbles.. as long as we use linear/datetime axis it will be fine. But logarithmic axis for example won't work. If you found an issue with linear/datetime axis, let me know - this could be a bug and we should fix this in the core.